# Remove zooming in next image changed

Tags: android

i am facing one issue related in pinching zoom in android imageview. I am using the following code for image pinching zoom. http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/pinching-zoom-in-android-image-view-or.html.

I am using this pinch zooming for array of images in image view.. Here i issue is if i zoom in first image then i move into second image mean the second image also display with zoom. But if i change next image it should not display with zoom. when i pinch for that particular image that time only i will get zoom.